# Playing youtube video in UIWebView only using iFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to play youtube videos on my `UIWebView` using `<iframe>` tag with below code -

```
NSString *html = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {    background-color: transparent;\
color: white; \
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/efRNKkmWdc0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></iframe>\
</body></html>";

UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0)];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Its working fine.

[image]

But, i need to play this on webview itself not using iPhone default player. How do i restrict this to play on `UIWebView` only. I was defined the `iframe` player class as `class=\"youtube-player\"` also. But, its taking iPhone's default player.

Any idea appreciated!

Comment: Hi... Praveen... Did you get solution for this?.. please help me

Comment: @Jack1231 Nope. Still not. But, i'm sure. Every video in iOS can't play without using its quick time player. So, it may not possible in iOS

Comment: @Praveen Did you find any answer? facing the same problem. Searching for the solution from last 2 months

Answer (score 3):

Try using this code to initialize the iframe player:

```
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
                               height: '100%',
                               width: '100%',
                               videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                               playerVars: {
                                 'controls' : '0',
                                 'playsinline' : 1
                               }
                               });
```

Note the "playsinline" parameter being set to 1. In the containing view, initialize the UIWebView with this parameter:

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

One thing I've noticed is that you cannot set the baseURL parameter to NULL; it has to be an NSString. Here's an example that loads an HTML file named iframe-player.html containing the required HTML and JavaScript code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"iframe-player" ofType: @"html"];
NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error: &error];

[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
```

Comment: Do you have an example project. It isn't playing inline for me

Comment: its working but how to get delegate method called when player ready and state change etc

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Web videos are always in full screen on iPhone.
The only possibility to play video in your app is to use MPMoviePlayer and add the view to your screen. But then you need to have a direct link to the video file